# URL updated in history but not in print-preview (firefox)

Tags: javascript, browser-history, html5-history, print-preview

I'm trying to set-up printing for our bands website. Currently i struggle with the url. The page loades on first visit the actual whole page and if you select any internal link, only the content of one central div is loaded (via JQuery). That all works and the URL in the history is updated accordingly.

However, when you select print preview, you get the first URL by which you visited the page.

For example: [Silberschauer/Kokain](http://silberschauer.de/songs/kokain.html)), when you select print-preview, you get the current URL. Now click the menu-button 'media' and select songs. The history is updated. But when you select print-preview again from the browsers menu, you get the actual page with the initial URL (still http://silberschauer.de/songs/kokain.html).

It works in IE, is there anything i can do about that bug?

Comment: This is most definitively a bug, filed it [to bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1016913)